# XNA Framework: Manipulating screen brightness

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am working on a project for Game with XNA Framework.

I am using a `OptionsMenuScreen` class to display different game options/settings to the user.

I have added two `UP` and `DOWN` buttons (`Texture2D`) on the screen that would increase or decrease the screen's brightness.

I am not able to find the logic I would need to use to manipulate the brightness of the screen.

I would really appreciate if you can please point me into the right direction.

Here is the relevant code:

---

```
class OptionsMenuScreen : MenuScreen
{
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    MenuEntry brightness;
    Texture2D brightnessUp;
    Texture2D brightnessDown;

    ContentManager contentManager;

    public OptionsMenuScreen() : base("Options")
    {
        brightness = new MenuEntry("Brightness");
        MenuEntries.Add(brightness);
    }

    public override void LoadContent()
    {
        if (contentManager == null)
        {
            contentManager = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");
        }

        brightnessUp = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("handup");
        brightnessDown = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("handdown");
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch = ScreenManager.SpriteBatch;

        var brightnessDownPosition =
            new Vector2(brightness.Position.X - 50, brightness.Position.Y - 12);

        var brightnessUpPosition =
            new Vector2(brightness.Position.X 
                + brightness.GetWidth(this) + 8, brightness.Position.Y - 12);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(brightnessDown,
            new Rectangle((int)brightnessDownPosition.X, (int)brightnessDownPosition.Y,
                30, 30), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Draw(brightnessUp,
            new Rectangle((int)brightnessUpPosition.X, (int)brightnessUpPosition.Y,
                30, 30), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus, bool coveredByOtherScreen)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, coveredByOtherScreen);

        foreach (TouchLocation t in TouchPanel.GetState())
        {
            if (t.Position.X >= brightnessDown.Bounds.Left
                && t.Position.X <= brightnessDown.Bounds.Right
                && t.Position.Y >= brightnessDown.Bounds.Top
                && t.Position.X <= brightnessDown.Bounds.Bottom)
            {
                // What should I do here?
            }
            else if (t.Position.X >= brightnessUp.Bounds.Left
                && t.Position.X <= brightnessUp.Bounds.Right
                && t.Position.Y >= brightnessUp.Bounds.Top
                && t.Position.X <= brightnessUp.Bounds.Bottom)
            {
                // What should I do here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks a lot for looking into this :)

Answer (score 3):

[According to this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/29643.aspx), there are several ways you can go about it:

- Use [`GraphicsDevice.SetGammaRamp(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.setgammaramp%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)
- Use a black texture and alpha transparency
- Adjust materials and/or lights on textures for all objects in the scene
- Per-pixel color recalculation using a pixel shader

The first option is the easiest, but has some drawbacks (ugly graphical effects while you're setting it up - mostly effects just the options menu), and isn't always supported.

You could use [`SupportsFullScreenGamma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevicecapabilities.drivercaps.supportsfullscreengamma%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) and [`CanCalibrateGamma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevicecapabilities.drivercaps.cancalibrategamma%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx) to determine if it is supported, and fall back to another method if it isn't.

**Edit**

On Windows Phone 7, [some of these options might not be available to you](http://www.sgtconker.com/2010/06/windows-phone-7-xna-brightness-and-contrast/).

That site (currently broken, but if you google it you can find a cached copy) suggests you use the full-screen quad with alpha blending approach, with these specific blending modes:

```
Brightness: source = ZERO, dest = SOURCECOLOR
Contrast: source = DESTCOLOR, dest = SOURCECOLOR
```

Here's some code (stolen from that article):

```
// In your game class:

Texture2D whiteTexture;

// In LoadContent:

whiteTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
whiteTexture.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.White });

// In the appropriate class (the game class? not sure...):

int brightness;
int contrast;

BlendState brightnessBlend;
BlendState contrastBlend;

// In Initialize:

brightness = 255;
contrast = 128;

brightnessBlend = new BlendState();
brightnessBlend.ColorSourceBlend = brightnessBlend.AlphaSourceBlend =  Blend.Zero;
brightnessBlend.ColorDestinationBlend = brightnessBlend.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceColor;

contrastBlend = new BlendState();
contrastBlend.ColorSourceBlend = contrastBlend.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
contrastBlend.ColorDestinationBlend = contrastBlend.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceColor;

// In Draw:

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, brightnessBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(whiteTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800), new Color (brightness, brightness, brightness, 255));
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, contrastBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(whiteTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800), new Color(contrast, contrast, contrast, 255));
spriteBatch.End();

GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
```

Comment: I found the same code as well, the issue is implementing it in my OptionsMenuScreen class which inherits from GameScreen class.  The GameScreen class doesnt have the same methods as the Game1.cs class template which you have pasted above.  So how do I get these two classes to work together which both have methods that I need to use?

Comment: @Mash: Sorry, don't have XNA installed so I can't check it out.  If you can get access to one instance from the other, you can easily bridge the gap with public properties/methods.  I'm thinking you'd expose those brightness and contrast properties publically, and leave the rest in the game class since it doesn't need to be accessed directly.  If it turns out to be much harder than what I suggested, and you end up figuring it out, I suggest adding your own answer to show what you did to help people out who have the same problem.

Comment: @Mash: One way to get access to the screen class from the game class is by passing the game class through the constructor.  This will probably only work if you manually construct the screen class from some code inside the game class.  Again, I don't have XNA installed and haven't touched it in like 2 years, so I can't remember for sure...